# Only want Copy and Share from UIMenuController, but code still being wonky

Tags: ios, swift

Here's what my textView looks like right now. It is a textview inside a scrollview.

I am trying to replace the usual UIMenuController menu items with Save and Delete but not getting there. Can someone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, {

var selectedStory : URL!

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var textSlider: UISlider! {
    didSet {
        configureSlider()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyText = try? String(contentsOf: selectedStory)
    textView.text = storyText

    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHandler))
    longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 0.3 // 
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)
}

// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizer

@objc func longPressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.state == .began,
        let senderView = sender.view,
        let superView = sender.view?.superview
        else { return }

    senderView.becomeFirstResponder()

    UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(senderView.frame, in: superView)
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
}

extension UITextView{
override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == Selector(("_copy:")) || action == Selector(("_share:"))
    {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
}
extension UIScrollView{
override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == Selector(("_copy:")) || action == Selector(("_share:"))
    {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }


   }
}
```

I'm getting 2 issues:

1. When I tap the screen, only the Share is showing up and the Copy is not.
2. The Share button shows up randomly near the center, not on the text that is selected, [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHONT.png)

Comment: UITextView's superview is UIScrollView, why you are placing UITextView inside UIScrollView? if you will remove UIScrollView, Share button will display at perfect place.

Comment: Thank you! I got rid of the scrollView and that fixed issue #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove **`UITextView`** that is inside **`UIScrollView`** because **`UIScrollView`** itself is the parent class of **`UITextView`**. It will place the **`UIMenuController`** at appropriate frame.

Remove **`longPressGR`** and **`longPressHandler`** methods.

Replace this method,

```
extension UITextView{
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action.description == "copy:" || action.description == "_share:" {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

You will get following output.

[image]